# Android Studio GridLayout is hidden

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have only completed the xml portion of this project, so there is no added code to the .java page.  I am using a LinearLayout as base and then adding a GridLayout with buttons.  I can see the buttons contained in the GridLayout in Design view however the background color is not displaying `android:background="@color/white"` - so each numerical number button is:

```
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
```

in colors.xml defined:

```
    <color name="black">#2E2C2C</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

the textColor is displaying in Design view but not the background:

[image: Here is the image in Design view (Android Studio)]

From the Design view the background color is not displaying - when opening up in my phone nothing displays, buttons are hidden:

[image: View from Samsung phone as run from app]

below is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHistory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center|end"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center|end"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="AC"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMulti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="*"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
            android:text="="
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="."
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `themes.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.CalculatorEx" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I don't think I need to add the .java code as I've not touched it - only starting with the xml and then will build the .java - I just want to start from a solid base before proceeding.

thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please show your `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @zyngot - just added in `themes.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems - first is that the button width is too wide for the phone, if you turn the phone to landscape the buttons will appear.  Second issue is that newer versions of Android Studio do not allow you to change button background colors as the button bg color defaults to `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>` (from `themes.xml` page)

**Fixes:**

1. Button Width: simply change the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for each button - to something like this `android:layout_width="50dp"` and now all buttons are displayed on the phone screen
2. Button bg color: the problem is the `themes.xml` page, specifically the `parent` attribute from the `<stlye...>` tag - changed this:

```
<style name="Theme.CalculatorEx" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
<style name="Theme.CalculatorEx" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

after those changes, changing bg colors within the xml code (e.g. - `activity_main.xml`) works perfectly!